# Publish error | smart publish or Republish - publish everything is stuck in initializing and does not finish

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.1

Publish error | smart publish or Republish - publish everything is stuck in initializing and does not finish

We have upgraded sitecore application from 6.2 to 7.1 recently. We are facing a critical issue when we try to publish the created items in the upgraded application where Smart Publish or Republish-Everything stuck in "Initializing" stage and will never finishes.

We have removed the staging module which was performing the media publish from CM to CD and implemented the scalability setting by enabling the scalabiltysettings.config and configuring the webdeploy.config with proper folder and permissions set. No issue with user permission and folder settings observed.

```
Sitecore version 7.1 13090
Sitecore\Admin and client specific accoungs with Admin role
```

Please let us know what is causing the issue. Also, revert back if you need more info.

Comment: Are there any errors in the log files?

Comment: What measures have you already taken to attempt to fix this?  Have you done an IISReset or any Application Pool Resets on the box?

Comment: We tried increasing the MaxWorkerThreads to 100. It works fine. Publish wizard will still be stuck in "Initializing..." for more than 1 minute and then it starts processing. This happens even for one single item with 1 or 2 children also.

Comment: When we start the publish wizard, it tries to load ModallessDialogs.js and throws 404 error ModallessDialogs.js. How can we handle this? 
File Path: /sitecore/shell/client/Speak/assets/lib/externals/ModallessDialogs.js.

Answer (score 0):

This normally happens when your History table is excessively large. Try cleaning it out (under most circumstances it's completely safe to do so) and see if your publish starts picking up quickly.

If you are in an environment with many item changes, you might also oconsider decreasing the default 30 day lifetime of History table entries.

```
<Engines.HistoryEngine.Storage>
    <obj type="Sitecore.Data.$(database).$(database)HistoryStorage, Sitecore.Kernel">
        <param connectionStringName="$(id)" />
        <EntryLifeTime>30.00:00:00</EntryLifeTime>
    </obj>
</Engines.HistoryEngine.Storage>
```